# Replacing gulp-browserify with browserify and recieving 'pipe is not a function' error

Tags: gulp, node-modules, browserify

I have the following which worked with gulp-browserify but I am now using `browserify` with which the following produces an error in the code which was originally written to work with the `gulp-browserify` module:

```
gulp.task('client', function () {
  gulp.src('client/js/main.js')
      .pipe(browserify({
        transform: ['hbsfy'],
        extensions: ['.hbs']
      }))
      .pipe(rename('hearthclone.js'))
      .pipe(gulp.dest('./client/build'));
});
```

I receive the following error:

> [18:30:14] TypeError: gulp.src(...).pipe(...).pipe is not a function

I'm not sure how to modify this to work with browserify.